# How to write rules for proguard?

Tags: java, android

I was need to make implementation of proguard in my project

my default proguard settings were like this

```
android {
...///

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

....////
}
```

Then I made some little changes

```
android {
...///

release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

....////
}
```

There is my `proguard-ruler.pro` file  https://ideone.com/ccPvPv

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/Shahar/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
 #and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

#If you not sure about proguard process so uncomment next line
#-dontobfuscate

# view res/layout/design_layout_snackbar_include.xml #generated:18
#-keep class android.support.design.internal.SnackbarContentLayout { <init>
(...); }

# view res/layout/activity_main.xml #generated:11
#-keep class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout { <init>(...); }

# view AndroidManifest.xml #generated:19
#-keep class ru.jollydroid.athdemo.MainActivity { <init>(...); }

#

# Proguard configuration for Jackson 2.x (fasterxml package instead of 
codehaus  package)
#-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
#    public <methods>;
#    protected <methods>;
#}
#-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
#    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
#}
#-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }


#-----------------
#-keepnames com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** { *; }
#
#-keepnames com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
#
#-keepnames cryptix.util.test.** { *; }
#
#-keepnames jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.** { *; }
#
#-keepnames cryptix.util.gui.** { *; } 
#
#-keepnames ui.activities.** { *; }
#
#-keepnames ui.adapters.** { *; } 
#
#-keepnames ui.fragments.** { *; }
#
#-keepnames webServices.controllers.** { *; }
#-------------------------

#Was worked
#-----------------
#-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
#
#-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
#
#-dontwarn cryptix.util.test.**
#
#-dontwarn jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.animators.**
#
#-dontwarn cryptix.util.gui.**
#
# -dontwarn ui.activities.**
#
#-dontwarn ui.adapters.**
#
#-dontwarn ui.fragments.**
#
#-dontwarn webServices.controllers.**
#-------------------------

#-dontwarn java.awt.**
#-dontwarn java.beans.Beans
#-dontwarn javax.security.**
#-keep class javamail.** {*;}
#-keep class javax.mail.** {*;}
#-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
#-keep class com.sun.mail.dsn.** {*;}
#-keep class com.sun.mail.handlers.** {*;}
#-keep class com.sun.mail.smtp.** {*;}
#-keep class com.sun.mail.util.** {*;}
#-keep class mailcap.** {*;}
#-keep class mimetypes.** {*;}
#-keep class myjava.awt.datatransfer.** {*;}
#-keep class org.apache.harmony.awt.** {*;}
#-keep class org.apache.harmony.misc.** {*;}

# Proguard configuration for Jackson 2.x (fasterxml package instead of 
codehaus 
 package)


#-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** { *; }
#
#-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
#
#-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.models.** { *; }
#
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
#-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
#-keep class android.content.res.Xm.ResourceParser.** { *; }
#-keep class com.googlecode.** { *; }
#-dontwarn com.parse.**
#-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
#-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
#    native <methods>;
#}
```

I tried a lot of different way to make a rules for libs, but doesn't work

And there output that I get if I am trying make build apk in release mode.

https://ideone.com/Lg8tOT

So as far as I understand I get this issue because I need to add rules for external libs.

I saw this resource

https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets

but it doesn't help me...

I am not a strong in proguard , so tell me please how I can add this rules?

If I understand correctly I need to write my custom rules, but how to do it?

Feel free to ask

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Make changes https://gist.github.com/albinmathew/c4436f8371c9c41461ab

Now gradle looks like

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
```

My `proguard-rules.pro`

https://ideone.com/kxsCEh

My errors now

https://ideone.com/JhCE3o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why and how , but code below works for me perfectly.

so my grade now looks like this

```
android {
...///

buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

...///

}
```

and there is my `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-ignorewarnings

-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

also I checked result of obfuscation and it is really work.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to set rules for `Proguard`, is default configuration giving you any error ?. Anyway, check this links for detail information about `Proguard`

https://gist.github.com/albinmathew/c4436f8371c9c41461ab
https://gist.github.com/Jackgris/c4a71328b1ae346cba04

Default configuration means you just put lines that is,

```
minifyEnabled true
useProguard true
shrinkResources true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

By this lines Gradle use default Proguard rules.

> Dexguard (commercial version of Proguard)

If want to make more secure your code you can use `Dexguard`. `Dexguard` is a commercial version of `Proguard`, because `dexguard` comes with `string encryption` feature that makes code more secure.

Comment: What do you mean default configuration?

Comment: Made changes and also added them to question, take a look please

Comment: Firstly, why do you want to use proguard for removing bloat code or anything else ?

Comment: I need to obfuscate my code... Make it more difficult for reverse - engeenering

Comment: okk then you just have to add `minifyEnabled true` in your gradle. But if  you want to make more secure your code you can use `Dexguard`. `Dexguard` is a commercial version of `Proguard`

Answer (score 1):

`shrinkResources true` will compress your images (`png`, `jpeg`, etc)

`minifyEnabled true` will obfuscate you code.

Those two rules will shrink you code and the apk will be more light.

Since `minify` is enabled, you need to put some rules, rules that you put in `proguard-rules.pro` in order to keep classes unobfuscated because some methods needs to be visible for use.

For example, you have a class used by Firebase, `User`. Methods and fields from that class need to be visible in order to be functional. Firebase will convert response to that class and needs to be visible.

```
#-keep class .User.** {*;}
```

Some rules are defined by libraries and you need to add them in order to build the project.

Warnings can be avoided with `-dontwarn` rule.

```
-dontwarn cryptix.**
```

Comment: So just for my understanding . Look I have this warning `Warning:cryptix.util.test.TestGUI: can't find referenced class java.awt.TextComponent` , if I undertstood you correctly , I need to do next  '#-keep class cryptix.util.test.TestGUI.** {*;}` ? Yes?

Comment: That's a warning. Should be disabled with `-dontwarn`. I will edit my post.